# Hot water twin impeller pump wiring to my boiler

Tags: plumbing, wiring, water-heater, water-pressure

I have installed a new Stuart Turner Monsoon twin impeller pump to increase the hot water pressure in my house.

The pluming side of things seems to have gone well, however, I am not receiving any hot water through my taps at all where as previously I would get hot water but at a slow dribble.

Is it possible that the wiring I have replaced between my hot water boiler and the new pump could be interfering with each other and preventing me getting any hot water?

I have attached some pictures below so you can understand the setup.

[image: Wiring]

[image: Wiring2]

[image: Water pump]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Ash

Comment: [Installation instructions](http://www.stuart-turner.co.uk/media/5173-Monsoon-Standard-Single-and-Twin-ShowerPump-WholeHousePump-IG.pdf).

Comment: Thanks,

I do have this manual already however clearly I'm not smart enough to have figured it out with the manual.

Any other suggestions? 

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean anything by posting a link to the user manual. I just found it, but didn't have time at the moment to read through it. So I thought somebody else might be able to use it to help you.

Comment: The user manual mentions "integral pump isolating valves", are those open? Does the motor make any noise or indication that it's running?

Comment: That's no problem, I didn't take it like that.

The motor does run and the valves are open.

I just cannot get any hot water out of any of the taps.

I have a feeling it's an airlock problem, but can't seem to get rid of it

Comment: Do you have the inlet and outlet to the pump reversed?

Comment: If the pump is running, it's likely not an electrical problem.  Your plumbing looks different than the manual, is there a reason you plumbed it like that?

Comment: Pay close attention to: inlet and outlet min. and max. head pressure and temperature specs., priming and commissioning instructions. If the pump is "gassed up" you might try opening a downstream tap, turning on the pump, then slowly closing off the discharge (outlet) valve (not all the way closed though) to see if you can establish flow.

Comment: Looking at the photo, I am thinking your pump may be "running away" from its' suction and "gassing up". The instructions show independent suction lines. Can you increase suction pressure somehow to see if that changes performance?

Comment: the photo shows you have the two impellers plumbed in parrellel just boostating either hot or cold but not both

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at figure 5 in the manual. (Or any of the other figures)

None of them show you connecting the pipes in parallel across the pump.

The cold comes in and out one side of the pump in series. The hot comes in and out the other side of pump.

Check your plumbing in the picture against figure 5.

They are not the same.

Do you have just the hot water coming in and you are trying to use bothe sides of the pump for hot instead of hot and cold?